# Micro Collections in Phalcon (Object of class can't be converted to string)

Tags: php, collections, phalcon

I am trying to make a micro API in Phalcon that uses collections so I can separate logic into controllers.

```
use Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault,
   Phalcon\Mvc\Micro,
   Phalcon\Mvc\Micro\Collection as MicroCollection;

// Use Loader() to autoload our model
$loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();

$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
  'BookApp\Controllers' => __DIR__ . '/bookapp/controllers/',
  'BookApp\Models' => __DIR__. '/bookapp/models/',
  'BookApp' => __DIR__ . '/bookapp/'
));

$loader->register();

....

$app = new Micro();
$app->setDI($di);

$users = new MicroCollection();
$users->setHandler(new \BookApp\Controllers\UserController(), true);
$users->setPrefix('/user');
$users->post('/', 'register');
$users->get('/{id}', 'getUser');
$users->delete('/{id}', 'deleteUser');
$users->put('/{id}', 'updateUser');
$users->post('/{code}/confirm', 'confirmEmail');
$users->post('/{id}/reset', 'resetPassword');
$app->mount($users);
```

This issue is on the $app->mount(). It is telling me it needs a collection from not \Phalcon\Mvc\Micro\Collection but a \Phalcon\Mvc\Collection. Yet the latter does not have the needed methods. If I try the above code I get:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class BookApp\Controllers\UserController could not be converted to string
```

Thanks for any help anyone can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of `Class Phalcon\Mvc\Micro\Collection` states that the `$handler` argument is of type `mixed`:

```
public Phalcon\Mvc\Micro\CollectionInterface setHandler (mixed $handler, [boolean $lazy])

    |Sets the main handler
```

Try handing the name of your Controller as a string.
Since you want lazy loading (2nd argument) there is no need to create an instance of the controller while registering it.

```
$users->setHandler('\BookApp\Controllers\UserController', true);
```

Comment: You should probably either use single quotes or double back-slashes for the class name to avoid ambiguity:
`php -r 'echo "My\really\neat\class";' //
eally
eat\class`

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/micro.html#using-controllers-as-handlers), you can either pass an object to `setHandler`, or a string name with `true` for the second parameter for lazy-loading. You appear to have combined the two, so it's trying to resolve your object as a name to load.

Either pass the name of the class as a string, or remove the second parameter from your setHandler call.